# Find groups of articulation points

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have some undirected graph and I try to find articulation points. There is example

[image: img1]

It has one articulation point - vertex #2.

But I also want to find #4 and #5 as articulation group points. Because joint removing of #4,#5 also cut graph into unconnected subgraphs. I imagine example graph as a 3 connected subgraphs.

[image: img2]

How can I find specified cut-points?

Comment: Are there any more conditions for the cut-point groups?
Because there can be a huge amount of such groups. E.g. (1, 14), (0, 1, 15), (6, 9), (11, 7, 8, 9), ... I think there can be even exponential many of them.

Comment: I think that is by the size of such groups. Cut-points should separate large clusters of nodes

Comment: You have to be more specific. What means "large"? why 4-5 is acceptable and 6-9 is not?

Comment: With what you've given I don't think there's a much better solution than checking all possible groups. The first thing to do is RIGOROUSLY DEFINE WHAT YOU MEAN BY A GROUP. It's fine to leave variables in the definition. But the more restrictions allowed (e.g. that they must be nodes of a subtree of given maximum size) increase the likelihood of an _efficient_ algorithm. Otherwise, pretty sure you can encode a SAT problem in the selection, which would make the problem NP hard, meaning there's nothing with run time exponential in the maximum group size. I'll let a proof to you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any faster method other than loop through all combination as you don't have any restriction. (I even don't think this test is meaningful.)

Though programming language is not specified, please let me to use python as example.

When you are doing articulation points searching, the most well-known method is Tarjan’s algorithm. I think everyone reading this know it, so I will skip it as a function if you don't mind, where you can find in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/.

```
class Graph:
   #From www.geeksforgeeks.org
def worker(g, prefix, arr, u):

    container = g.graph[u]
    if u in g.AP():
        print prefix
        arr.append([prefix])
        del g
    else:
        for i in container:
            if str(i) not in prefix.split(' '):
                new_prefix = prefix + ' ' + str(i)
                new_g = copy.deepcopy(g)
                new_g.combineNode(u, i)
                if len(new_g.graph) > 1:
                    worker(new_g, new_prefix, arr, i)

struct = {
    0:[1,12,13,14,15],
    1:[2,12,14,15],
    2:[3,4,5,14],
    3:[4],
    4:[5,6],
    5:[6,9],
    6:[7,8,9],
    7:[8,10,11],
    8:[9,10,11],
    9:[10],
    10:[11],
    12:[15],
    13:[14,15]
} 
g1 = Graph (total)

for key,value in struct.iteritems():
    for child in value:
        g1.addEdge(key, child)

result = []
for i in range(0, total):
    print 'Remove root ' + str(i)
    worker(g1, str(i), result, i)
print result
```

I write it in case that only **the least length of group** to divide the graph. As, lets say (4, 5), if it is already the AP, **any points** connect to them should be AP as well.

Just in case, anyone want the full Testing code. https://gist.github.com/MichaelKHTai/c438fd0911d0584be1e37f1fd1599b7e

Besides, it should be optimized by skipping duplicated group of nodes, like (4,5) and (5,4).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to find "2-connected component"s of your graph.

A 2-connected graph is a graph which is connected **and** doesn't contain any articulation points.

Edges of any simple graph can be partitioned into some 2-connected subgraphs.

The first example:

[image: a sample graph]

In the above graph, following are the 2-connected components:

- 4–2 3–4 3–1 2–3 1–2
- 8–9
- 8–5 7–8 5–7
- 6–0 5–6 1–5 0–1
- 10–11

The second example:

[image: a sample graph]

Each color corresponds to a 2-connected component. Multi-colored vertices are cut vertices (articulation points) and thus belong to multiple 2-connected components.

**I think each component is an answer to your question.
You can use Tarjan algorithm to find these components. Its time complexity is O(|V| + |E|) or O(n + m).**

```
time = 0
function DFS(vertex, adj[][], low[], disc[], parent[], visited[], V, stack)
    disc[vertex]=low[vertex]=time+1
    time = time + 1
    visited[vertex]=true
    child = 0
    for i = 0 to V
        if adj[vertex][i] == true
            if visited[i] == false
                child = child + 1
                push edge(u,v) to stack
                parent[i] = vertex
                DFS(i, adj, low, disc, visited, V, time, stack)
                low[vertex] = minimum(low[vertex], low[i])
                if parent[vertex] == nil AND child > 1
                    while last element of stack != (u,v)
                        print last element of stack
                        pop from stack
                    print last element of stack
                    pop from stack
                if parent[vertex] != nil AND low[i] >= disc[vertex]
                    while last element of stack != (u,v)
                        print last element of stack
                        pop from stack
                    print last element of stack
                    pop from stack
            else if parent[vertex] != i AND disc[i] < low[vertex]
                low[vertex] = disc[i]
                push edge(u,v) to stack

fuction biconnected_components(adj[][], V)
    for i = 0 to V
        if visited[i] == false
            DFS(i, adj, low, disc, parent, visited, V, time, stack)
            while stack is not empty
                print last element of stack
                pop from stack
```

Sources:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biconnected-components/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/biconnected-components/tutorial/